# Working with tokens in the ethereum blockchain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am writing a test application that allows people to purchase tokens.

I am adapting the example from here: https://ethereum.org/token#the-code

Here are my questions:

1. What is the best way to have a registry of purchases? I would assume this can be a simple web interface that queries the block chain to see who has bought what.

If this is correct, does this mean running geth on a server in order to have the latest blockchain available and then using some kind of PHP / Javascript library in order to query the blockchain every so often?

2. What is the best way to sell tokens? Could this be done via a web interface or would it be best to sell via the ethereum wallet? Or both?
3. Lets say I want to split a token into a number of parts as such:

A: A full token = 1
B: 1/10th of a full token called a 10token
C: 1/10th of a 10token called a 100token
D: 1/10th of a 100token called a 1000token

What is the best way to represent this?

For instance, if someone owns a full token they have 100% of that tokens rights. However it would be possible for many parts of a token to be owned by different people who will share rights according to their share.

Visually, it would look something like this:

[image]

How to do this is a puzzle to me.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to have a registry of purchases? I would assume this can be a simple web interface that queries the block chain to see who has bought what.

You can do the registry in your token sale smart-contract by making event like this

  `event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);`

In this case you will be able to watch event log later and get all the addresses you need.

Another approach is to add a simple map to your contract like this `mapping (address => uint256) public deposited;` and add elements to this map on purchases.

About the representation of the registry for the users you better just take a look at ICO's you like and make it in the same way.

> What is the best way to sell tokens? Could this be done via a web interface or would it be best to sell via the ethereum wallet? Or both?

I would say both. But it depends on who are your tokens for. If you sell only using ethereum wallet you will loose a lot of users not familiar with blockchain.

> Lets say I want to split a token into a number of parts as such

Take a look at the solutions offered by [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) project. Just read their contracts code and I think you'll find solutions you were looking for in this post.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, very useful!